# Subjectivity of evaluation homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I am trying to prove that the evaluation homomorphism:

$ev_z:\mathbb{R}[X]\to \mathbb{C}, f\mapsto f(z)$ where $z=a+bi$  is surjective.

To start with, I don't really understand how the map is obtained. Do have a polynomial and we just change $x$ to $z=a+bi$? But how do we determine $a$ and $b$ for $z$?

Comment: Fix a $z \in \mathbb C$, hence the image of the homomorphism is

$$
\mathbb R [z] = \left\{f(z) | f \in \mathbb R[x] \,  \right\}= \left\{a_0+a_1z+\dots +a_n z^n | n \in \mathbb N, a_0,a_1,\dots, a_n \in \mathbb R  \right\}
$$

Comment: @SewerKeeper But how do we know which z corresponds to some value for x?

Comment: First you fix a comples number, for example $z = 1+ \operatorname i$. The homomorphism values every real polinomials in $1 +\operatorname  i$. For example the homomorphism maps $x^2 - 1$ into $(1+ \operatorname i)^2-1 =-1 +2 \operatorname i $.

Comment: @SewerKeeper Surjectivity seems very trivial. But how do we formally prove it?

Comment: Did you know the [Fundamental theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** My original answer was completely wrong, as I misread the question. My mistake was helpfully pointed out in the comments, and I have corrected it.

You are right that the map is obtained by substituting $z$ for $x$ in the expression of the polynomial. As for surjectivity, I'd note that the result is **only** true if $b \neq 0$, for if $z \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ for any real polynomial. So we assume $b \neq 0$, and proceed as follows.

We have $ev_z(1) = 1$ and $ev_z(X) = z = a + bi$. The latter gives us that

$$
ev_z(\frac{X-a}{b}) = i
$$

It is pretty clear then that for any real $u, v$, we have 
\begin{align}
u + vi &= ev_z(u) + v\cdot ev_z(\frac{X - a}{b}) \\
&= ev_z(u + v\frac{X-a}{b}) \\
&= ev_z\big(\frac{v}{b}X + (u-\frac{av}{b})\big)
\end{align}

Since every complex number is of the form $u + vi$ for some $u, v$, we have that $ev_z$ is surjective.

**tl;dr** for any $u + vi \in\mathbb C$, we have $f(X) = \frac{v}{b}X + (u-\frac{av}{b}) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, and it is trivial to check that 
$$
f(a + bi) = \frac{v}{b}(a + bi) + (u - \frac{av}{b}) = 0
$$

Comment: But $f$ should be in $\mathbb R[x]$, no?

Comment: @SewerKeeper Of course! I didn't read the question properly - thank you for pointing it out. I'll try to fix the answer.